ACM Template cannot use acknowledgements (acks)
In the ACM Journals Primary Article Template, I added the following code before the reference,
\begin{acks}
To Robert, for the bagels and explaining CMYK and color spaces.
\end{acks}

however, the content in the Acknowledgments is not displayed and no errors are reported.  I am very confused! This issue is very important to me, thanks for your help!

Welcome to TeX.SE. Please be more specific as to the document class and the document class options you employ.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Are you using anonymous mode in the article?  If yes, then acks are not be printed by design: the reviewer should not be aware that you know Robert.
